# Unable to start MongoDB. ERROR: addr already in use

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I tried running MongoDB in local server with **mongod** command and it failed to run. The error:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.392 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5127 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=leandrotk
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.392 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.392 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.392 [initandlisten] build info: Linux orlo 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_54
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.392 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.392 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.435 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.435 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.513 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [initandlisten] now exiting
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 dbexit: 
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.514 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.599 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.599 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.599 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.599 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.668 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sat Jan 31 13:07:16.668 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

you already have a process running

`killall mongod`

should kill the other process, if you have another kind of process bound to that port you could find it with `netstat | grep 27017`

Comment: I read MongoDB documentation suggesting to Never use kill -9 (i.e. SIGKILL) to terminate a mongod instance. see the mongoDB documentation - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#StartingandStoppingMongo-SendingaUnixINTorTERMsignal

Comment: Please suggest us harmless way of doing

Comment: @Vinay I didn't suggest `kill -9`... `man kill` doesn't specify a default signal, on my os x system the default is `15 TERM (software termination signal)`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
sudo service mongodb stop

sudo mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

some version is:

```
sudo service mongod stop

mongod: mongo damon
```