# MongoDB: `Address in use` Error even though Address is NOT in use.

Tags: macos, mongodb, sockets, unix, port

I have a newly installed version of MongoDB (v3.2.0) on my Mac. When I try running the command `mongod` I get this error:

> listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket:
>   0.0.0.0:27017

Even though the result of `$ lsof -i :27017`shows nothing is using that port.

**Here is the terminal output:**

```
Michaels-iMac:~ michael$ mongod
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=11485 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Michaels-iMac.home
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.0
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 45d947729a0315accb6d4f15a6b06be6d9c19fe7
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
    2016-01-07T13:38:00.098+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
    Michaels-iMac:~ michael$
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try with `sudo lsof -i :27017`. There might be mongods not started with the euid of your user.

Comment: That was good advice @MarkusWMahlberg. I tried that, but it still shows no processes running on that port.

Comment: Do a `telnet localhost 27017` and see what happens.

Comment: well, now it is magically running. All I did was delete the `/data/db` and make a new `/data/db` and ensured proper permissions, and now it's working. Still not sure what that would have to do with the original error through. Thanks for your willingness to help @MarkusWMahlberg. If you want to add an answer of 'things you can try' in this situation, I can mark it as the answer, because you were giving good advice that could help others in the future.

Comment: The original error could have been a socket linger.  See the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required and `man setsockopt`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @cdarke. I actually think that a socket linger is a good possibility.  Next time this happens, I will take that into consideration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start MongoDB. ERROR: addr already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253384/unable-to-start-mongodb-error-addr-already-in-use)