# mongo db error on startup ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

This is the error I get after starting mongodb. I have the /data/db directory setup. any suggestions? Thank you.

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01:/data# mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2017-04-06T01:49:24.295+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9631 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01
2017-04-06T01:49:24.296+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2017-04-06T01:49:24.296+0000 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2017-04-06T01:49:24.296+0000 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-04-06T01:49:24.296+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lgw01-12 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
2017-04-06T01:49:24.296+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-04-06T01:49:24.296+0000 [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-04-06T01:49:24.299+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2017-04-06T01:49:24.299+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2017-04-06T01:49:24.427+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2017-04-06T01:49:24.428+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
2017-04-06T01:49:24.443+0000 [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-04-06T01:49:24.443+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2017-04-06T01:49:24.443+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.443+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.443+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.444+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.444+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.444+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.446+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.448+0000 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2017-04-06T01:49:24.448+0000 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.448+0000 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2017-04-06T01:49:24.449+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2017-04-06T01:49:24.449+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: I just found the answer on another stackoverflow post here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253384/unable-to-start-mongodb-error-addr-already-in-use" Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you removing the question then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start MongoDB. ERROR: addr already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253384/unable-to-start-mongodb-error-addr-already-in-use)

Answer (score 0):

According to your log something is already running in mongod default port that is 27017. Just stop it and give a try.

use the following command to get the PID of the process

```
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 27017
```

copy the PID and execute the following

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```